# Error!when i ran npm start command for running react application

Tags: reactjs

Npm create-react-app my-app this command worked perfectly and created 
Me react application but when I run the npm start command it is showing me an error with errorstatus1

I have tried reinstalling nodemodules and deleting the nodemodules which are out of my project folder but none of these helped me. [This is the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlL0G.jpg). Help me in this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Remove `node_modules` and `lock` files
2. Edit `package.json` so the new version of `react-scripts` is `2.1.8`
3. `yarn install` / `npm install`
4. `cd your-app`
5. `yarn start` / `npm start`

Comment: I followed the above steps but Still the error remains

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Create-React-App a while ago? Create-React-App made some changes to the way you should install and run it.

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Try to uninstall it, and follow the new instructions on https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started

Also, verify that you have an updated version of node and npm.

Comment: I created the react app  by following the above link only but still there is an error